# jhipster import-jdl filter error creating entities filters

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

i have a project made with Jhipster 4.9, in my linux i have jhipster 4.13.3

when i run '**jhipster import-jdl src/model/Model.jdl**'

i get this error

*The jdl is being parsed.
An error has occurred:
        SyntaxError Error 
message:
        Expected "/*", "angularSuffix", "dto", "entity", "enum", "except", "microservice", "noFluentMethod", "paginate", "relationship", "search", "service", "skipClient", "skipServer", ['\n'|'\t'|'\r'|' '| | ], [A-Z_], or end of input but "f" found.*

This is my Model.jdl

```
/**
 * Generated by JHipster IDE plugin
 */

entity Region {
    regionName String
}

entity Country {
    countryName String
}

// an ignored comment
/** not an ignored comment */
entity Location {
streetAddress String
postalCode String
city String
stateProvince String
}

entity Department {
    departmentName String required
}



  /**
     * Task entity.
     * @author The JHipster team.
    */
    entity Task {
        title String
    description String
}

/**
 * The Employee entity.
 */
entity Employee {
    /**
    * The firstname attribute.
    */
    firstName String
    lastName String
    email String
    phoneNumber String
    hireDate ZonedDateTime
    salary Long
    commissionPct Long
}

entity Job {
    jobTitle String
    minSalary Long
    maxSalary Long
}

entity JobHistory {
    startDate ZonedDateTime
    endDate ZonedDateTime
    language Language
}

enum Language {
    FRENCH, ENGLISH, SPANISH
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Country{region} to Region
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Location{country} to Country
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Department{location} to Location
}

relationship ManyToMany {
    Job{task(title)} to Task{job}
}

// defining multiple OneToMany relationships with comments
relationship OneToMany {
    Employee{job} to Job,
    /**
    * A relationship
    */
    Department{employee} to
    /**
    * Another side of the same relationship
    */
    Employee
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    Employee{manager} to Employee
}

// defining multiple oneToOne relationships
relationship OneToOne {
    JobHistory{job} to Job,
    JobHistory{department} to Department,
    JobHistory{employee} to Employee
}

// Set pagination options
paginate JobHistory, Employee with infinite-scroll
paginate Job with pagination

dto * with mapstruct

filter * except JobHistory,Region
// Set service options to all except few
service all with serviceImpl except Employee, Job

// Set an angular suffix
angularSuffix * with mySuffix
```

The .jdl show no errors in eclipse.
I am trying to implement filtering entities.

Anyone can help me.

Comment: Have you tried the debug option to get more info? `'jhipster import-jdl src/model/Model.jdl --debug`

Comment: thank you for your answer, i tried with the debug option, but didn't give me more information.          The jdl is being parsed.
An error has occurred:
        SyntaxError
Error message:
        Expected "/*", "angularSuffix", "dto", "entity", "enum", "except", "microservice", "noFluentMethod", "paginate", "relationship", "search", "service", "skipClient", "skipServer", ['\n'|'\t'|'\r'|' '| | ], [A-Z_], or end of input but "f" found.
Position:
        At l.113.

Comment: I have imported successfully your JDL with JHipster 4.13.3, it works also in https://start.jhipster.tech/jdl-studio/ so I suspect that you are not using 4.13.3 Can you check by running `jhipster --version` in your project directory? Maybe you have installed it only globally and not locally.

Comment: yes, thank you i did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my project to jhipster 4.13.3 and it seems to work. but the code is generated with errors, class Location_ , Country_ with references in the code but don't exist anywhere. So i have to create de classes @StaticMetamodel(Employee.class) public class Employee_

Comment: This is normal, these are the JPA static metamodel used for filtering that gets generated by build, see the doc http://www.jhipster.tech/entities-filtering/ Just run mvnw